# How to schedule categories?

Tags: categories, taxonomy, scheduled-posts

Is there anyway to schedule categories? like I already created the categories but I don't want it published to the public until the scheduled date like how you can schedule posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could schedule a function to be called using a cron job. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron

When you're done, you could probably unregister the cron job from inside the function so it isn't called repeatedly.

Comment: Is there a easier solution? I'm not really a programmer

Comment: Not that I know of. I've never heard of any wanting to schedule a category so this may be something that's more unique and needs developing from scratch. Perhaps you could hire someone to do it for you, or search for a plugin?